# jquery alert executes first before other statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a following js script:

```
$('#uploadForm').submit( function () {
    var fileExists;

    // display loader
    appendData();
    // alert('first');

    if((typeof reference !== 'undefined') && reference) {        
        alert('second');    
    }
    return false;
});

function appendData() {
    $div = $("<div></div>");
    $div.addClass("overlay");
    $div.attr("id", "overlay-procurement");
    $div.append("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>");    
    $("#upload_container").append($div);
}
```

Order of execution, on submitting a form:

1. `alert('second')` inside `if-else` statement pops-up.
2. After clicking on `OK`, the loader appears.

But with `alert('first')` the order is normal.

Why is it showing this behavior?

Comment: try to use use callback

Comment: Basically a callback is a function passed in as a parameter to another function. JavaScript can do this because functions are first-class objects.